# find the values of a, b and c from sin graph

Tags: trigonometry

> [image]
>
> The diagram shows part of the graph of a function whose equation is 
>   $y = a\sin(bx^{\circ}) + c$
>
> (a) Write down the values of a, b and c.
>
> (b) Determine the exact value
>   of P where the graph intersects the x-axis as shown in the diagram.

For part a, I can say that the amplitude is 2 because it covers 1 to -3.  I am confused why d is not in this equation as the graph has been vertically shifted -1 units or is it that c is -1 in this graph?

For B or the period, a period of 1 is $360^{\circ}$ but this graph only goes to 120 so ${360\over120} = 3$,so b is 3.

The phase shift is $-c\over b$ so it is $-1\over3$.

I am not sure how to find part b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a=2, b=3, c=-1

To solve part (b), you need to solve the trigonometric equation
$2\sin(3x^\circ)=1$
The solution P is then 50 degrees. (There is another solution at 10 degrees, but that is not P).

Answer (score 1):

The amplitude is indeed $2$, as $\frac{1}{2}(\max(f) - \min(f))$. The average lies at $\frac{1}{2}(\max(f) + \min(f))$ which is $-1$, so the shift downwards is $c = -1$. The amplitude is $a$, so $a = 2$.

There is no phase shift (this would correspond with a number $p$ in $\sin(t-p)$), but there is a type of acceleration, which affects the period. The period is $120^\circ$, instead of $360^\circ$ so there is a threefold increase. The graph is at $120$ degrees where it normally would be at $360$. So $b \cdot 120 = 360$, so $b = 3$.

So in total: $y = 2\sin(3x) -1 $